# How to display circular image in Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have an Image control and a list Images and I want to display the Image in a circle.
It means that I want to display a circular image in my windows store apps.

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 5):

Place image inside Border element, and set CornerRadius:

For WinRT/Windows Store App:

```
<Ellipse Height="100"  Width="100">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="url"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
```

For WPF:

```
<Border Height="100" Width="100" CornerRadius="50">
    <Border.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Rect="0,0,100,100"/>
    </Border.Clip>
    <Image Source="url"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: No this is not solving my problem, when I write that then my Image corner is displaying outside the Border. I want to clip the Image circular in Windows store XAML App.